# In MySQL, how do I add a new column that calculates different values based on different variables within the same column?

Tags: mysql

I created a data table.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydatabase;
USE mydatabase;

CREATE TABLE crop_yield (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    replicate INT,
    variable VARCHAR(15),
    yield DECIMAL(5, 2)
);

INSERT INTO crop_yield (replicate, variable, yield) VALUES
    (1, 'Control', 116.08),
    (2, 'Control', 132.85),
    (3, 'Control', 115.98);

INSERT INTO crop_yield (replicate, variable, yield) VALUES
    (1, 'Treatment', 131.37),
    (2, 'Treatment', 108.89),
    (3, 'Treatment', 100.35);

select * from mydatabase.crop_yield;
```

[image]

Now, I'd like to add/subtract or multiply/divide yield, but according to different variables.

For example, I'd like to add 20 in Control, and minus 10 in Treatment. So I used the below code.

```
ALTER TABLE mydatabase.crop_yield ADD COLUMN new_yield INT;

UPDATE crop_yield
SET new_yield = CASE
    WHEN variable='Control' THEN 20
    WHEN variable='Treatment' THEN -10
    ELSE 0
END;
```

However, it does not work. Could you please let me know how to calculate new values according to each variable?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What were you expecting instead of what you got?

Comment: It works for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vMkHVPsRo1y6zD8oppjDMN/0

Comment: your query works fine maybe you want this result https://dbfiddle.uk/tRtAtCkL

Comment: @nbk Perfect!!! That's what I wanted!! Many thaks

Comment: @Barmar I found that I should disable "Safe Updates" to run the code. Thanks!!

Comment: Why is `new_yield` an `INT` if you're adding and subtracting to a `FLOAT`?

Comment: @Barmar I don't know. I just combine several codes from website? What should it be? Maybe Double??

Comment: It should be `DECIMAL(5, 2)` just like `yield`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to include the original yield in the ‘THEN’ part…

```
ALTER TABLE mydatabase.crop_yield    
ADD COLUMN new_yield INT;

UPDATE crop_yield
SET new_yield = CASE
    WHEN variable='Control' THEN yield+20
    WHEN variable='Treatment' THEN yield-10
    ELSE yield
END;
```